# How can I override Django Model's save() method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model which looks like this.

```
import uuid

from django.db import models


class TemplateId(models.Model):

    id = models.SmallAutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    template_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    template_id = models.UUIDField(max_length=255, default=uuid.UUID, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.template_name)

    class Meta:
    ordering = ('-id',)
```

I have another function/code where I'm calling an API to fetch the `template_name` and `template_id` and store it in dB. But every time when I get a response from the API, I want to override the the whole table (`everytime deleting old record and then adding the new records`)

currently I'm doing this:

```
def fetch_template_id():
    
    api_response = # calling the API
    for template_id in api_response:
        obj = TemplateId(template_id=template_id["id"], template_name=template_id["name"])
        obj.save()
```

In order to override, I tried overriding the save method in my `TemplateId` model as below but it didn't work

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TemplateId, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Since the data gets saved in the model fields by getting the API response, next time when same data is received from the API response, it throws duplicate data error in the dB.
**How do I override all the dB fields with each API call?**

Answer (score 0):

If the objects exists, update it. If it doesn't, create it.
def fetch_template_id():

```
    api_response = # calling the API
    for template_id in api_response:
        try:
            obj = TemplateId.objects.get(template_id=template_id["id"])
            obj.template_name=template_id["name"]
        except:
            obj = TemplateId(template_id=template_id["id"], template_name=template_id["name"])

        obj.save()
```

Comment: No, I don't want to update the table. template_name and template_id are two different columns of TemplateId table. I want to truncate the table then add fresh records with every API call. I tried doing `TemplateId.objects.all().delete()` but this doesn't show the table itself when I look for it in pgAdmin app. It says ' Error fetching rows: Error message: The specified object could not be found.'

Answer (score 0):

If by override you mean update the `template_name` of a particular template `id`, you need to change:

```
    obj = TemplateId(template_id=template_id["id"], template_name=template_id["name"])
    obj.save()
```

to

```
     obj = TemplateId.objects.get(id=template_id["id"])
     obj.template_name = template_id["name"]
     obj.save()
```

Because in your case you are searching for a particular entry with the 2 conditions, but do not change anything when saving it. `save` method can stay as is, not need to override it

Comment: No, I don't want to update the table. template_name and template_id are two different columns of TemplateId table. I want to truncate the table then add fresh records with every API call. I tried doing `TemplateId.objects.all().delete()` but this doesn't show the table itself when I look for it in pgAdmin app. It says ' Error fetching rows: Error message: The specified object could not be found.'